# Web Automation that can also run Unix Commands

Tags: unix, web, automation

Does anyone know of web automation software/app that also can run unix scripts?  I know of the standard ones, but can't find out whether I can also run Unix scripts.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty common to multitask like that inside of Selenium WebDriver automation code.

For example, you could write a Selenium test in Python that also launches arbitrary external programs/scripts via Python's built-in support for executing commands.